# Color conversions

Tags: c++, algorithm, colors

My program reads from a png file many letters. The letters are black in white bg, as shown bellow.

[image]

I want my program given the colour values of those letters be able to print the letters in any text colour in any background colour. For example, I want to display 'a' using green text in blue background.

---

Using the following code I can change the text colour to any colour:

```
Color c;
c.r = original_black.r + ((255 - original_black.r) / 255.0) * desired_colour.r;
c.g = original_black.g + ((255 - original_black.g) / 255.0) * desired_colour.g;
c.b = original_black.b + ((255 - original_black.b) / 255.0) * desired_colour.b;
```

Result:

[image]

**Question:** How to update the above code to change the bg color to any color, as shown bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Initial picture contains different colors (probably, like ClearType pixel rendering for LCD monitors). It is difficult to pick an acceptable way for colored edge pixels for all back-fore color combinations.
So I'd suggest to transform colors of initial picture to gray levels. One of the possible formulas:

```
Y = 0.299 R + 0.587 G + 0.114 B  [0..255 range]
```

And use this value as alpha in alpha blending

```
c.r = (foreground.r * Y  + (255 - Y) * background.r) / 255
```

and so on